# Android activity reopening without disturbing the stack

Tags: android, android-navigation

Here is the Activity navigation stack:
Activity A > Activity B > Activity C

Activity C is a WebView, each time the user opens it I want it to reopen as it was so the user will still see what was previously done inside the WebView.
So this Activity C is opened with flag FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT, and to be able to reopen it I don't want to finish it, so the onBackPressed of Activity C has been changed and starts again the calling Activity with following code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, Class.forName(callingActivity));
startActivity(intent);
```

This works (C reopens well with was was previously done) but the problem is that when doing so the Activity C becomes the parent of the Activity B in the stack, so it loops between B and C and I cannot return to Activity A:
C > B > C > B > C > B ...

Any idea of how I could handle this navigation properly ?

Comment: How you are trying to change the View? With the Hard Back Button??

Comment: Yes I'm always going back with the back button

Comment: you could Override the onBackButton() in your activity and direct to the Intente you want. Have you tried this?

Comment: onBackButton does not exist, are you talking about onBackPressed ? If so, I already do this.

Comment: Yea...another way you can do it is by saving the current and previous activity on PREFS file (It works like a Session on Android)

Answer (score -1):

Use super.onBackpressed() on Activity C again.
You should use the flag FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP instead of FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT, try it and tell me if it worked as intented.

If that doesnt work you can always use Intents on the onBackPressed to assure your navigating to the correct activity

Comment: sorry i know how things work here but i  need reputation to be able to comment

Comment: This doesn't work, the navigation stack is not disturbed but the Activity C is opened as a new Activity and lost previous content.

Comment: As I said I am already using Intent on the onBackPressed to go back to the Activity B without finishing the Activity C.
But because Activity C is opened with flag FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT it disturbs the navigation stack and becomes parent of B.

Comment: Yep sorry i was wrong, you got to go to your manifest and define launchMode for Activity C, in our case singleTop https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html?hl=es-419#lmode

Comment: launchMode with singleTop doesn't work, the Activity C is still recreated each time I open it again.

Comment: have you read the docs? maybe singleInstance works, i did something similar in the past and i remembered using singleTop